# 3つの引数をもつ C++ typedef の意味

Tags: c++

Boost.Proto Users' Guide を読んでいるのですが、そのなかの

```
typedef typename Context::template eval<Expr>::result_type type;
```

という構文の意味が理解できずにいます。
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/proto/users_guide.html#boost_proto.users_guide.back_end.expression_evaluation.proto_eval

C++ の typedef の引数は２つであると思っていたのですが、３つの場合がありうるのでしょうか？

そうであるなら、どのような意味を持つのでしょうか？
あるいは、typedefの引数は２つの場合しかないならば、上記構文の　typename Context::template　はどのような意味を持つと解釈すれば良いのでしょうか？

恥ずかしながら、typedef の使い方にをひととりおさらいしたつもりなのですが、上記構文の意味はわかりません。ヒントやtypedefについての解説へのURLだけでも助かりますので、どうか宜しくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

俗に「template限定子」と呼ばれる構文が使われており、そのせいでトークンが分割されてみえています。
ここでは`typename Context::template eval<Expr>::result_type`型に`type`という別名を宣言しています。

```
typedef typename Context::template eval<Expr>::result_type type;
```

（余談ですが、typedefの引数という表現はあまり正確じゃない気はします。意味は通じますけど。）

---

C++11言語仕様では [temp.names]/p4 に記載があります。

> When the name of a member template specialization appears after `.` or `->` in a postfix-expression or after a nested-name-specifier in a qualified-id, and the object expression of the postfix-expression is type-dependent or the nested-name-specifier in the qualified-id refers to a dependent type, but **the name is not a member of the current instantiation (14.6.2.1), the member template name must be prefixed by the keyword `template`.** Otherwise the name is assumed to name a non-template. [ Example:
>
> ```
> struct X {
>   template<std::size_t> X* alloc();
>   template<std::size_t> static X* adjust();
> };
> template<class T> void f(T* p) {
>   T* p1 = p->alloc<200>();          // ill-formed: < means less than
>   T* p2 = p->template alloc<200>(); // OK: < starts template argument list
>   T::adjust<100>();          // ill-formed: < means less than
>   T::template adjust<100>(); // OK: < starts template argument list
> }
> ```
>
> -- end example ]

Comment: ありがとうございます。
     typedef typename Context::eval<Expr>::result_type type;
と書いてあったほうが、私には分かりやすかったのですが、この構文では、コンパイラは < を より小さい演算子だと見なしてしまうのですね。（「プログラミング言語 C++」 C.13.6 を見落としておりました。）

これで、template限定子は、そのようにコンパイラに誤解させないためのものであり、また、 人間にも、eval<Expr> がメンバテンプレートであり、<>のなかの型が明示的に限定されていることがはっきりと示されていると理解できました。

実際、この typedef 構文が現れた Boost.Proto Users' Guide を読み進めていくと、 たしかに、Contextクラスはメンバテンプレート eval< テンプレート引数 > を持っています。

なるほど、すべての辻褄があいます。

Comment: ココで使われているtypenameとtemplateは、コンパイラへの曖昧さ解消を伝えるための構文要素ですね。これらが無いと、型名ではなく識別子(変数／関数)に、テンプレート名ではなく通常の識別子と解釈されてしまいますから。

Answer (score 5):

一見４つに見えますが、中のうちのひとつは`修飾つき識別子`であり型表記の一部です。
typedef で型の別名をつけているわけですが
既にある元の型名 `Context::template evel<Expr>::result_type`
新しくつける別名 `type`
なので typedef の引数はやはり２つです。

`Context::template` というのは 入れ子名前指定子 という奴です。
ISO/IEC 14882:1998 JIS X 3014:2003 5.1 - 7
後続の識別子 `eval<Expr>::result_type` の検索を `Context` クラス名の中に限定します。
`result_type` が型であることを明記する必要があるので `typename` が必要です。

```
typedef struct mystruct value_type;
```

を typedef に引数３つって言わないのと同じです。

Comment: Boost.Protoの難しさに圧倒されてしまいましたが、質問の構文も typedef 型の名前 型の別名; と解釈すべきものなのですね。もうひとつの回答と合わせて、理解することができました。ありがとうございます。